# Replace numeric values for text values

Tags: r, replace, lookup

I have a matrix of number values of 0-8 which I would like to replace with descriptive values. My current matrix is as follows:

```
Muni<-c("Town1","Town2","Town3","Town4","Town5")
Company1<-c(0,4,2,8,1)
Company2<-c(5,5,0,1,4)
Company3<-c(1:5)
Company4<-c(8,4,3,1,8)
(Matrix<-cbind(Muni,Company1,Company2,Company3,Company4))
#      Muni    Company1 Company2 Company3 Company4
# [1,] "Town1" "0"      "5"      "1"      "8"     
# [2,] "Town2" "4"      "5"      "2"      "4"     
# [3,] "Town3" "2"      "0"      "3"      "3"     
# [4,] "Town4" "8"      "1"      "4"      "1"     
# [5,] "Town5" "1"      "4"      "5"      "8"
```

I would like to replace the numeric values with the following descriptive values

```
Response<-c(1:8)
Description<-c("0-1","2-5","6-10","11-15","16-20","21-30","31+","I don't know")
(Values<-cbind(Response,Description))
#      Response Description   
# [1,] "1"      "0-1"         
# [2,] "2"      "2-5"         
# [3,] "3"      "6-10"        
# [4,] "4"      "11-15"       
# [5,] "5"      "16-20"       
# [6,] "6"      "21-30"       
# [7,] "7"      "31+"         
# [8,] "8"      "I don't know"
```

I've tried

```
replace(Matrix,Values$Response,Values$Description)
```

but am not getting the new values being replaced by the initial numeric code.

Comment: How did you want to handle the `"0"` values in `Matrix`?

Comment: They should be labelled 0-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `match` to look up each element of `Matrix` in the `Response` column of `Values` and then grabbing the corresponding `Description` value:

```
Matrix[,-1] <- Values[match(Matrix[,-1], Values[,"Response"]),"Description"]
Matrix
#      Muni    Company1       Company2 Company3 Company4      
# [1,] "Town1" NA             "16-20"  "0-1"    "I don't know"
# [2,] "Town2" "11-15"        "16-20"  "2-5"    "11-15"       
# [3,] "Town3" "2-5"          NA       "6-10"   "6-10"        
# [4,] "Town4" "I don't know" "0-1"    "11-15"  "0-1"         
# [5,] "Town5" "0-1"          "11-15"  "16-20"  "I don't know"
```

If instead your `Matrix` variable were really a data frame with the data stored as factors (as suggested in your comments), you could include a call to `as.character` and `unlist`:

```
Mat2[,-1] <- Values[match(as.character(unlist(Mat2[,-1])), Values[,"Response"]),"Description"]
Mat2
#    Muni     Company1 Company2 Company3     Company4
# 1 Town1         <NA>    16-20      0-1 I don't know
# 2 Town2        11-15    16-20      2-5        11-15
# 3 Town3          2-5     <NA>     6-10         6-10
# 4 Town4 I don't know      0-1    11-15          0-1
# 5 Town5          0-1    11-15    16-20 I don't know
```

Data:

```
Mat2 <- data.frame(Muni = c("Town1", "Town2", "Town3", "Town4", "Town5"),
                   Company1 = factor(c(0,4,2,8,1)),
                   Company2 = factor(c(5,5,0,1,4)),
                   Company3 = factor(c(1:5)),
                   Company4 = factor(c(8,4,3,1,8)))
```

Comment: Josilber- Thank you for your response. This works fine for the example I posted. When I apply this to my actual data it does not work. This may be because the municipality names in my actual data are factors and the values are integers. In the example I posted all columns are "chr." Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

an *alternative* `dplyr` solution

```
# install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
data.frame(Matrix) %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(Values[,2][match(., Values[,1])]), -Muni)
#     Muni     Company1 Company2 Company3     Company4
# 1 Town1         <NA>    16-20      0-1 I don't know
# 2 Town2        11-15    16-20      2-5        11-15
# 3 Town3          2-5     <NA>     6-10         6-10
# 4 Town4 I don't know      0-1    11-15          0-1
# 5 Town5          0-1    11-15    16-20 I don't know
```

if you want to get back to a matrix you can obviously do `as.matrix(data.frame(Matrix) %>% mutate_each(funs(Values[,2][match(., Values[,1])]), -Muni))`

Comment: @danny, if you update your lookup table to `Response<-c(0:8)` and `Description<-c("0-1", "0-1","2-5","6-10","11-15","16-20","21-30","31+","I don't know")` this should work. This also demonstrate the important of making your working example match your actual data as closely as possible.