# replace numeric value by string value

Tags: r, string

I'm a beginner in R. I'm trying to replace the numeric value "1" in my data frame by the name of the column its cell is stored.

This is the reproductible example I've been trying:

```
name1 <- c("1", "0", "0")
name2 <- c("0", "1", "0")
name3 <- c("0", "0", "1")

nameCollection <- cbind(name1, name2, name3)

names <- colnames(nameCollection)

for (j in 1:ncol(nameCollection)) {
  for(i in 1:nrow(nameCollection)) {
    if(nameCollection[i,j] == 1){
      nameCollection[i,j] <- names[i]
    }
  }
}
```

It works when you run the code above, but not with the actual data frame (a csv file).

This is the error message R is printing when I try it with my data frame:

> Error in `[.data.table`(a, i, j) : 
>     j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'j' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[,..j] or DT[,j,with=FALSE]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.

If someone knows what I need to do, please give me a help.

Thanks!

p.s: I tried this approach - [Replace numeric values for text values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002102/replace-numeric-values-for-text-values) - but it is not actually what I'm trying to do.

Comment: please give a reproducible example and the expected output

Comment: If you use 'dput()' to get data to paste here, it'll be easier for us to try out various solutions and ultimately help you!

Comment: I did some edits in my question, let me know if it has helped.

Comment: Your error refers to a data.table. Your updated code starts with a matrix. Your question text refers to you using a data.frame. Those are three different things. Can you clarify?

Comment: Wow, I thought these were the same thing and we could navigate them in the same way. In this case, it is a data frame and I need to navigate through it and whenever I find 1, I have to replace it with the column name which stores this cell.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally use data frames, however below you will find one way to accomplish this with both a data frame and a matrix. There are other ways to do this, but this will get you there.

```
name1 <- c("1", "0", "0")
name2 <- c("0", "1", "0")
name3 <- c("0", "0", "1")

#With at data frame
df_nameCollection <- data.frame(name1, name2, name3, stringsAsFactors = F)
df_names <- colnames(df_nameCollection)

for (name in df_names) {
  #The following selects all of the columns named name then all of the
  #values equal to 1 and sets them to name
  nameCollection[name][nameCollection[name] == "1"] <- name 
}

#With a matrix
m_nameCollection <- cbind(name1, name2, name3)
m_names <- colnames(m_nameCollection)

for(i in 1:length(m_names)){
  m_nameCollection[,i][m_nameCollection[,i] == "1"] <- m_names[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a `data.table` then you might as well do the following:

```
name1 <- c(1,0,0)
name2 <- c(0,1,0)
name3 <- c(0,0,1)

nameCollection <- cbind.data.frame(name1, name2, name3)
library(data.table)
dat=setDT(cbind.data.frame(ind=row.names(nameCollection),nameCollection))
dcast(melt(dat,"ind")[,v:=`is.na<-`(variable,value==0)],ind~variable,value.var = "v")[,2:4]
   name1 name2 name3
1: name1    NA    NA
2:    NA name2    NA
3:    NA    NA name3
```

using base R:

```
nameCollection[]=Map(function(x,y)replace(x,x==1,y),nameCollection,names(nameCollection))
nameCollection
  name1 name2 name3
1 name1     0     0
2     0 name2     0
3     0     0 name3
```

Answer (score 0):

why can't you find and replace before binding the variables into a dataframe? that way you avoid for-loops.

```
# your original code
name1 <- c("1", "0", "0")
name2 <- c("0", "1", "0")
name3 <- c("0", "0", "1")

# substitute all instances of 1 with the string name
name1 <- gsub(x = name1, pattern = "1", replacement = "name1")
name2 <- gsub(x = name2, pattern = "1", replacement = "name2")
name3 <- gsub(x = name3, pattern = "1", replacement = "name3")

# bind it to a dataframe, not a matrix (you originally did matrix but in your question you say it's a dataframe
nameCollection <- as.data.frame(cbind(name1, name2, name3))

# this is the output
> nameCollection
  name1 name2 name3
1 name1     0     0
2     0 name2     0
3     0     0 name3
```

this solution is super simple too!